# Extract the Source IP Address from two different log samples with regex

Tags: regex, bro, qradar

I have a regular expression as follows:

```
"id.resp_h"|"rx_hosts":(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}),
```

I am trying to extract the Source IP Address from two different log samples. "id.orig_h" and "tx_hosts" are two different fields for Source IP. How do i ignore the speech marks and square brackets? i just want extract the IP addresses

```
schema_id=17127524534057985804:skip_writers="":{"_path":"conn","_system_name":"hostname","_write_ts":"2020-01-12T22:09:28.853417Z","ts":"2020-01-12T22:07:14.642074Z","uid":"Cm4cbmvRjlmd2I52c","id.orig_h":"192.168.1.1","id.orig_p":xxx,"id.resp_h":"192.168.1.2","id.resp_p":xxx,"proto":"udp",

schema_id=17223896091372211545:skip_writers="":{"_path":"files","_system_name":"Hostname","_write_ts":"2020-01-12T22:09:00.016260Z","ts":"2020-01-12T22:07:14.108217Z","fuid":"FnmzOv3Fkhr8lP0qL","tx_hosts":["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.1"],"rx_hosts":["192.168.1.10"],
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :-)

Thanks,
JM

Comment: This looks like JSON content, and you should probably look into using a JSON parser, rather than regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to solve it with regex:

> (?:"id.resp_h"["[:]*|"rx_hosts"["[:]*)(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/QcA2tr/2)